# The word for "professional system" or "task system"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation, terminology

I work with software engineering and in norwegian (I'm from Norway) we have a word, "fagsystem", which refers to a software system/application that is specialized to handle a certain kind of business or professional context. Examples are my best bet to clarify, I guess:

- A banking back-end system that keeps track of a customers transactions and bank engagement
- An insurance back-end system that keeps track of a customers insurance premiums
- An airline booking system
- ...<

I've tried using translate.google.com but the translations seem a bit funny:
"professional system", "task system", "specialized system".

I would be very thankful for any suggestions on how to express this in English.

Comment: There really isn't a single term for this. Marketing divisions love to come up with new terms to describe their exact software package. I would check to see if your competitors are using an English phrase and start from there.

Answer (score 2):

Various examples,

- [CRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management) = Customer relationship management
- [ERM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employee_relationship_management) = Employee relationship management
- [Workflow Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_Management_System)
- [ECM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_content_management) = Enterprise content management

But what you might be looking for is the grand-daddy of all
[ERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning) = Enterprise resource planning

Alternatively,

> Enterprise Resource Planning and Management.

Very general terms that can be used on application of any type of software on a company-wide level

- Enterprise solution
- Enterprise system

e.g.,

> Representatives from oracle assured us that they have an enterprise solution for our requirements, by packaging various enterprise systems together.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a previous answer, *application software* may be an appropriate term.  The phrase *enterprise infrastructure software* is not in wide use (so far as I know) but *[enterprise software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_software)* is a commonly-used phrase.  According to wikipedia, *enterprise software* (also called *enterprise application software* or *EAS*) is purposed-designed computer software used  by organizations such  as businesses, schools, clubs, retailers, government, etc, as opposed to software used by individuals.

An older term (which may be jargon) is *stovepipe systems* or *stovepipe software*, which refers to closed-source vertically-integrated software systems that cannot share information with other applications used in an organization.  Most airline reservation software, banking software, defense-program software, and various industrial software systems fell into this category during the early decades of computer use; and some software in those areas still does.  This use of the word *stovepipe* is reflected in the following sense shown in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stovepipe):

> A channel for body of information which is compartmentalized in such a manner that some parties which might be interested in its use or be able to utilize it are restricted from access to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, I still feel that wordings such as _Enterprise Software_ or _Enterprise Application Software_ still is a bit fuzzy in a context where I'm trying to describe different bits and pieces of a system. 'Everything' can be described as _Enterprise Software_ depending on context. As such it is not explicitly enough to communicate the fact that I'm referring to the businessy, core parts.

Comment: I agree that *enterprise* terms are fuzzy or nonspecific, but disagree they apply to “everything”.  Many or most enterprise-software-stuff vendors characterize their packages as usable for management of the largest of companies (eg Fortune 500 companies), which is quite different from how ordinary small-business packages for taxes, payroll, and accounts payable or receivable are characterized.

Comment: In my line of work, every piece of software we construct is called *application software* or *application*.

Answer (score 1):

The adjective "dedicated" might be what you want here. The phrase "a dedicated <...> system" is not uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible phrase, if you need to distinguish it from more general applications, might be ***industry-specific system***.

Comment: Not bad, but still kind of fuzzy in my opinion. Until a better alternative comes around however, I've used "core business system"

Answer (score 0):

All of the examples you gave are examples of Transaction Processing Systems, often shortened to Transaction Systems.

Wikipedia has this to say about [Transaction Processing Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing_system):

> Transaction processing is a style of computing that divides work into
>   individual, indivisible operations, called transactions. A
>   transaction processing system (TPS) or transaction server is a
>   software system, or software/hardware combination, that supports
>   transaction processing.

In reality, most application software which deal with either incremental changes or financial operations can be modelled as transactional.

Answer (score 0):

> Line-of-business application

might be the term you're looking for

Comment: Can you cite established usages of this term that match?