# How would you call the main software used by a company

Tags: terminology, programming

I'm looking for a word designating the main software of a company. I know the term *line of business application*, but I never heard anyone say "this is *our* line of business application", only "this is *a* line of business application."

I'm looking for the term designating the class of software applications that are the only ones to be at the heart of a company. A CRM is in this idea, since we often say "this our CRM software"; however, the software I'm trying to qualify goes beyond customer relationship management as it also takes care of the daily operations.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which of [these three definitions](http://searchcio.techtarget.com/definition/LOB) for LOB are you using? Specifically, are you asking about ***3rd-party*** s/w that's vital to the operation of a company, the main application ***sold*** by a s/w house, or the ***general type*** of s/w they sell?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks a lot for your interest, I am using the 2nd definition. I'm talking about in-house software that is vital to the operation of a company. I've been thinking about it and I'm keen on going with "Operations Management s/w" what do you think ?

Comment: I think most companies would normally use "the same" software for, say, the sales ledger, purchase ledger, stock control, etc. But they might use a completely different supplier for their payroll & personnel records, so I don't really think many companies would need a name for "**the**" software they use, because they probably use several different systems (all of which might be considered "vital"). For the main product sold by a software house, I'd use ***flagship** application*.

Comment: I regularly use the phrase "our line of business software" to describe the core software used by our company.

Comment: Are you thinking of ERP software?  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning for details)

Comment: Possibly related: *[The word for “professional system” or “task system”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132658)* and *[A proper name for Microsoft software](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51801)*.

Comment: "Here Software!  Come here boy!  That's a good Software."  (Consider that "company" spans a pretty broad range, as does "software".  Some companies will outsource virtually all of their bookkeeping (and have no other need for software).  Others will consider, say, their web sales app to be their "main" software, as it's more important than mere bookkeeping.  (What do you suppose Google considers to be their "main" software?)

Comment: Wow that's a lot of new comments, thank you for your interest. @FumbleFingers Yes absolutely I'm with you, to me the core of the business is its operations, not support functions like accountancy. Thank you for the word "flagship", I didn't know it.

Comment: @Nick2253 Interesting ! How would you name it then ? Basically, I'm trying to name the project. "Warehousing System", "Stock System", "ERP System", "CRM System" sound okay, but I have a doubt about "Line of business system"....

Comment: @Hellion I think we have it !!! Thank you very much. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indispensable, Essential, "Tool of the trade", "Staple item"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/611829/indispensable-essential-tool-of-the-trade-staple-item)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Enterprise Resource Planning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning) software (ERP for short) is a set of integrated modules that allow you to control many, most, or all aspects of your business from a single package: financials (General Ledger, Accounts Payable, Accounts Receivable), order processing, purchasing, manufacturing, inventory management, time & attendance, payroll, etc.

Most companies run only one such system<sup>1</sup>, unless they are dealing with an acquisition or merger; although it is certainly common to run an ERP system, but have elements that could be managed by that system run instead on some other software (for instance, many companies will have a separate payroll system, even if their ERP software has a payroll module available).

---

1: *(Or they are trying to consolidate down to one system, or at least they wish they were running only one.)*

Comment: Of course, "ERP" has a mildly unfortunate connotation.

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested in the comments, I think the term that fits the bill here is "Flagship." From [PCMag definitions](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/flagship-product):

> **"Flagship Product"** - A major product of a company, which is typically why the company was founded and/or what made it well known. For example, MS-DOS, Windows and the Microsoft Office suite have been flagship products of Microsoft. Photoshop is a major product of Adobe Systems, and the Mac, iPhone and iPad are flagship products of Apple.

Comment: A “flagship” product is what your company is known for making/selling, whereas the OP was asking about internal use.

Comment: Ah, yes, I concur with your observation, @StephenS. In the title of this post, I misread the word "used" as "produced". My mistake.